# General bivariate functions that satisfy Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: inner-product, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Have there been any study of general bivariate functions $f:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f(x,y)^2 \leq f(x,x)f(y,y)$. This comes up as a function I'm working with satisfies the asymmetric version $f(x,y)f(y,x) \leq f(x,x)f(y,y)$ that shows up in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133961/cauchy-schwarz-inequality-for-bilinear-forms-valued-in-an-abstract-vector-space?rq=1), but it is assumed $f$ is an inner product already. Ideally, since having an inner product implies C-S, could there be some requirements on $f$ to make it an inner product (besides the obvious axioms of an inner product)? Any results on these type of functions would be amazing.